# Task.WaitAll() on continuation task only delays execution of original task?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

**Background:**

I've got a console app which creates `Tasks` to process data from a DB (let's call them Level1 tasks). Each one of the Tasks creates its own Tasks again to process each part of the data that was assign to it (Level2 tasks).

Each of the Level2 tasks has a continuation task associated with it and the code used to do a `WaitAll` on the continuation tasks before moving on.

I'm on `.NET 4.0` (no `async`/`await`)

**Issue:**

This created a problem though - it turned out that if it is done this way, none of the Level2 tasks was started before all available Level1 tasks were scheduled. Which is not optimal in any way.

**Question:**

This seems to be fixed with changing the code to wait for both the original Level2 task AND its continuation task. However, I'm not entirely sure why this is the case.

Do you have any ideas?

The only thing that I could come up with is that - since the continuation task has not started, there is no point in waiting for it to complete. But even if that was the case I would expect at least SOME of the Level2 tasks to have started. Which they never did.

**Example:**

I created a sample console app that demonstrated exactly that behavior:

1. Run it as is and you will see that it's scheduling all the tasks first, and only then you start getting the actual lines written from within the Level2 tasks.
2. But comment out the marked block of code and uncomment the replacement and all works as expected.

Can you tell me why?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod());
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void SomeMethod()
    {
        var numbers = new List<int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i);
        }

        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before start task");

            var numberSafe = number;

            /* Code to be replaced START */

            var nextTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got number: {0}", numberSafe);
            })
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Continuation {0}", task.Id);
                });

            tasks.Add(nextTask);

            /* Code to be replaced END */

            /* Replacement START */

            //var originalTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Got number: {0}", numberSafe);
            //});

            //var contTask = originalTask
            //    .ContinueWith(task =>
            //    {
            //        Console.WriteLine("Continuation {0}", task.Id);
            //    });

            //tasks.Add(originalTask);
            //tasks.Add(contTask);

            /* Replacement END */
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `ContinueWith`, or can you use `async/await`?

Comment: @Noseratio - it's .NET 4.0 - no async/await

Comment: You can still have it for .NET 4.0, if you use VS2012+: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info

Comment: @Noseratio - VS 2010 I'm afraid

Comment: Then your code really has to be completely re-factored, this may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx

Comment: @Noseratio - can you explain your point?

Comment: My point is to use correct task composition and iteration patterns for `ContinueWith`. I'll post it as an answer, as time allows.

Comment: What are the level 1 tasks in your example and what are level 2?  The result of `StartNew` is level 1 and the continuation is level 2?

Comment: @PeterRitchie - Level1 is the task created in the `Main` method (which should execute `SomeMethod`), Level2 task is the task created in the `SomeMethod` code (followed by the continuation task)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are seeing the `Task Inlining` behavior. Quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> In some cases, when a Task is waited on, it may be executed synchronously on the Thread that is performing the wait operation. This enhances performance, as it prevents the need for an additional Thread by utilizing the existing Thread which would have blocked, otherwise. To prevent errors due to re-entrancy, task inlining only occurs when the wait target is found in the relevant Thread's local queue.

You dont need 100 tasks to see this. I've modified your program to have 4 Level 1 tasks (I have quad core CPU). Each level 1 task creates only one level 2 task.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod(j)); // j as level number
    }
}
```

In your original program the `nextTask` is the continuation task - so I just simplified the method.

```
private static void SomeMethod(int num)
{
    var numbers = new List<int>();

    // create only one level 2 task for representation purpose
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        numbers.Add(i);
    }

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before start task: {0} - thread {1}", num, 
                              Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        var numberSafe = number;

        var originalTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got number: {0} - thread {1}", num, 
                                    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });

        var contTask = originalTask
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Continuation {0} - thread {1}", num, 
                                    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            });

        tasks.Add(originalTask); // comment and un-comment this line to see change in behavior

        tasks.Add(contTask); // same as adding nextTask in your original prog.

    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Here is sample output - on commenting `tasks.Add(originalTask);` - which is your first block.

```
Before start task: 0 - thread 4
Before start task: 2 - thread 3
Before start task: 3 - thread 6
Before start task: 1 - thread 5
Got number: 0 - thread 7
Continuation 0 - thread 7
Got number: 1 - thread 7
Continuation 1 - thread 7
Got number: 3 - thread 7
Continuation 3 - thread 7
Got number: 2 - thread 4
Continuation 2 - thread 4
```

And some sample output - on keeping `tasks.Add(originalTask);` which is your second block

```
Before start task: 0 - thread 4
Before start task: 1 - thread 6
Before start task: 2 - thread 5
Got number: 0 - thread 4
Before start task: 3 - thread 3
Got number: 3 - thread 3
Got number: 1 - thread 6
Got number: 2 - thread 5
Continuation 0 - thread 7
Continuation 1 - thread 7
Continuation 3 - thread 7
Continuation 2 - thread 4
```

As you can see in second case when you wait for `originalTask` on same thread that started it, the `task inlining` will make it run on the same thread - which is why you see the `Got Number..` messages earlier.

Comment: That's interesting - I'll read up on that and do some more testing with that in mind.

Comment: I found all the answers very helpful - since you were the first one to  explain it (and with a helpful example), I'll mark yours as accepted. Thanks

Comment: @JoannaTurban: Glad it helped. If you are considering alternatives, you should have a look at `TPL.Dataflow` and the `BufferBlock<>` there. It is asynchronous/non-blocking producer-consumer data structure you an use with async/await.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is the **blocking** `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())`. The default TPL task scheduler will not use a new pool thread for *each* task you start with `Factory.StartNew`. And you start 100 Level1 tasks, each blocking a thread with `Task.WaitAll`.

This creates a bottleneck. With the default size of `ThreadPool`, I'm getting ~20 threads running concurrently, with only 4 of them actually executing simultaneously (the number of the CPU cores).

Thus, some tasks will only be queued and will be started later, as the earlier tasks are getting completed. To see what I mean, try changing your code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod(), 
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` will give you the desired behavior, but this of course would be a **wrong** solution.

The **right** solution is to avoid a blocking code where possible. You should be doing the blocking wait at the topmost level only, if you have to do it all.

To address this, your code can be re-factored like below. Note the use of `ContinueWhenAll`, `Unwrap` and (optionally) `ExecuteSynchronously`, that helps to eliminate the blocking code and reduce the number of pool threads involved. This version performs much better.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod(i)).Unwrap());
        }

        // blocking at the topmost level
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Task<Task[]> SomeMethod(int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod " + n);

        var numbers = new List<int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i);
        }

        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before start task " + number);

            var numberSafe = number;

            var nextTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got number: {0}", numberSafe);
            })
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Continuation {0}", task.Id);
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

            tasks.Add(nextTask);
        }

        return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), 
            result => result, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }
}
```

*Ideally*, in a real-life project you should stick with naturally asynchronous APIs wherever possible (e.g, ["Using SqlDataReader’s new async methods in .Net 4.5"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/20/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta.aspx)), and use `Task.Run` / `Task.Factory.StartNew` only for CPU-bound computational tasks. And for the server-side applications (e.g., ASP.NET Web API), `Task.Run` / `Task.Factory.StartNew` will usually only add an overhead of redundant thread switching. It won't speed up the completion of an HTTP request, unless you really need to do multiple CPU-bound jobs in parallel, hurting the scalability.

I understand the following might not be a feasible option, but I'd highly recommend upgrading to VS2012+ and using `async/await` to implement a logic like this. It'd be very well worth the investment, as it greatly speeds up the coding process and produces simpler, cleaner and less error-prone code. You still would be able to target .NET 4.0 with [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - that's an interesting alternative to consider and probably a more reliable solution to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, waiting on a task that has not yet been scheduled may execute it synchronously. (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/15/9907713.aspx)) It wouldn't be very surprising that this behavior would apply to your code in the alternative case.

Keeping in mind that the threading behaviour is highly implementation- and machine-dependant, what happens here is probably something in the lines of this:

- Given the delay between a call to [Task.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the actual execution of the task to the threadpool, most of the so-called "Level 1" tasks, if not all of them, are scheduled before the first of them gets actually executed.
- Since the default task scheduler uses .NET ThreadPool, all of the tasks scheduled here will likely be executed on a ThreadPool thread.
- Once a "Level 1" task gets executed, the scheduling queue(s) are all filled with "Level 1" tasks.
- Every time a "Level 1" task executes, it schedules as many "Level 2" tasks as required, but those are all scheduled after the "Level 1" tasks.
- When the "Level 1" task gets to the point of waiting all the continuations of the "Level 2" tasks, the executing thread enters the wait state.
- With many ThreadPool threads in the wait state, the program rapidly reaches ThreadPool starvation, forcing the ThreadPool to allocate new threads (likely more than 100 in total) to resolve the starvation
- Once the last of the "Level 1" tasks gets to call the wait state, the ThreadPool allocates at least one more extra thread.
- This lastly allocated extra thread can now execute "Level 2" tasks and their continuations for the first time, since all the "Level 1" tasks are done with.
- After some time, one "Level 1" task will have all his "Level 2" tasks compleded. This "Level 1" task will then wake from its wait and complete its execution, thus freeing another ThreadPool thread, and accelerating the execution of remaining "Level 2" tasks and continuation.

What changes when you use your alternative method, is that because you reference the "Level 2" task directly in the array of tasks to wait for, the Task.WaitAll method gets the chance to execute the "Level 2" tasks synchronously instead of idling away.
This could not happen in the initial case, because continuation tasks cannot be run synchronously.

In conclusion, waiting in ThreadPool threads was what lead you to thread starvation and to the strange behavior you observed. While the optimization in the code waiting for tasks made the thread starvation behavior fade away, it is clearly not something you should rely on.

To solve your initial problem, you would be better following the suggestion made by lil-raz of doing away with your inner tasks.

If you have access to C# 5.0, you could also consider using the async/await pattern to write your code without relying on waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that this code is truly not optimistic, as you create 100 tasks and it does not mean that you will have 100 threads, and inside each task you create two new tasks, you are over superscribing the scheduler. if those tasks are related to db reading why not to mark them as long processing and discard the inner tasks?

Comment: This is only an example to demonstrate the behaviour. The real app is doing a db call but that's not really part of the problem. They are not meant to be long running in any way. The question is - why the change in the code affects the processing in this way.